# After installation Of Gemini tool for Bug tracking, How to get connect with Server?

Tags: testing, bug-tracking, gemini

I have installed "Gemini" tool in my system for bug tracking, It has successfully installed, but it is not get connect to the server. I have followed the following link:
http://www.geminiplatform.com/support/install-webpi

I gave the site name as"Gemini" and the folder name of this files also "Gemini", and I gave the server database name as KITS-WM01\SQLEXPRESS. Now the files are installed successfully. But with which URL I need to give in the browser to get connect with the server. I have tried with http://gemini.com/Gemini, this and http://localhost/Gemini.com/Gemini and http://KITS-WM01\SQLEXPRESS.com/Gemini.

With which URL I should get connect to the sever. Please give me the reply as early as possible.

**EDIT** : I have got the URL to connect to my server, which is http://localhost/wonder/Default.aspx
But I am getting a message now :

```
Service Unavailable

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

Comment: Is your IIS application pool that the app uses started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install a web app using webpi you can click "Launch" at the end of install. If you click that you'l the url.

You can also open IIS on the web server and locate the website, click on browse.

Comment: I have tried with the Launch option, it takes the url as http://localhost/Gemini/Default.aspx, and it is not get connect to the Gemini site, It is giving error message "Service Unavailable". Can you please suggest me about the same. Thank you.

Comment: Open IIS manager and make sure that the site is running (you should see the play button enabled if it is not).

Answer (score 0):

try : http://KITS-WM01/Gemini

Hope this helps, 
Dave

Comment: No it is not working, can you please help me to connect the sever.